# Use std::tie to unpack return value will lead to additional cost?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Consider these two approaches

approach 1

```
std::tuple<TypeA, TypeB> res = function(args);
TypeA & a = std::get<0>(res);
TypeB & b = std::get<1>(res);
// use a and b as you want
```

approach 2

```
TypeA a;
TypeB b;
std::tie(a, b) = function(args);
// use a and b as you want
```

I'm considering what's the cons and pros of these two approaches.

Will approach 2 lead to additional cost? Or maybe they are totally equivalent?

and in `c++17`, the structure binding provides a more intuitively way to  unpack tuple

```
auto [ var1, var2 ] = tuple;
```

Will it bring any improvement compared to another two approaches list above? Or it's just syntactic sugar?

Comment: You could always compile and check the assembly.  I would suspect a  decent optimizer would make one and two the same.  If you can use C++17 I'd just stick with structured bindings as they look nicer

Answer (score 3):

I am assuing `function` returns `tuple<TypeA, TypeB>`.  In addition I am using `A` and `B` as aliases for `TypeA` and `TypeB` because I am lazy.

```
auto&& [a,b] = function(args);
```

This is syntactic sugar for approach 1.

Approach 2 first calls the default constructor on `a` and `b`.  It then uses `tuple<A&,B&>=operator=(tuple<A,B>&&)` to assign over `a` and `b`.  Then the temporary `tuple<A,B>` created in the return value to `function` is discarded.

For some types those operations have no observable effects, so the compiler is not required to do any work.  In other types there are observabe effects caused by creating a temporary object then assigning over it; in that case, the compiler must do those extra actions.

Optimizing `auto&&[a,b]` is going to be easier for the compiler, and it also supports a few additional cases like

```
struct function_retval { int a, int b; };
function_retval function( int arg );

auto&&[a,b] = function(7);
```

the additional benefit is that it doesn't have a pile of named variables you don't want to talk about in your code.  The actual holder of the return value becomes anonymous.  Also, `decltype(a)` isn't a reference, unlike case 1, because the standard says so, even though it actually is a reference.

(`auto&&` simply means that I don't care if I store the return value in a reference or a value; I use whatever `function` returns).